# Returning department courses in databases

Tags: python, sql, database

I think I have the right idea to do this function but I'm not sure why I get
this error when I test it. Can anyone please help me fix this?

```
cur.execute(q)
```

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
>   current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.

Current Attempt

```
def find_dept_courses(db, dept):
'''Return the courses from the given department.  Use  the "LIKE" 
   clause in your SQL query for the course name.'''
return run_query(db, '''SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM Courses WHERE
                        Course LIKE  (? + 'dept%')''')
```

Desired output

```
find_dept_courses('exams.db', 'BIO')

# [('BIOA01H3F',), ('BIOA11H3F',), ('BIOB10H3F',), ('BIOB33H3F',), 
#  ('BIOB34H3F',), ('BIOB50H3F',), ('BIOC12H3F',), ('BIOC15H3F',), 
#  ('BIOC19H3F',), ('BIOC32H3F',), ('BIOC37H3F',), ('BIOC50H3F',), 
#  ('BIOC58H3F',), ('BIOC59H3F',), ('BIOC61H3F',), ('BIOC63H3F',), 
#  ('BIOD21H3F',), ('BIOD22H3F',), ('BIOD23H3F',), ('BIOD26H3F',), 
#  ('BIOD33H3F',), ('BIOD48H3F',), ('BIOD65H3F',)]
```

query function:

```
def run_query(db, q, args=None):
"""(str, str, tuple) -> list of tuple
Return the results of running query q with arguments args on
database db."""

conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = conn.cursor()
# execute the query with the given args passed
# if args is None, we have only a query
if args is None:
    cur.execute(q)
else:
    cur.execute(q, args)

results = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
conn.close()
return results
```

Comment: A `?` in an Sqlite statement is a placeholder which must be filled with a concrete value (usually appended as parameter when executing the statement)

Comment: Ok so how do I fix this?

Comment: Try to remove the `? + ` part. This is not the best way to do it but should work.

Comment: I just get the empty list. I don't get the desired output.

Comment: Check my edit. I added the query function.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are using a placeholder but do not pass any parameters. Secondly, you are concatenating placeholder `?` with a data value in `LIKE` expression.

Simply separate query statement and data value and leave `?` by itself:

```
def find_dept_courses(db, dept):
    sql = '''SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM Courses WHERE Course LIKE ?'''

    return run_query(db, sql, args=(dept+'%',))
```

Comment: Did you run my proposed solution?

Comment: Yes, and I get this error now cur.execute(q, args)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.

Comment: Hmmm...very odd! Are you sure you are passing a scalar string like *BIO* and not a list for *dept*?

Comment: Yes.  find_dept_courses(db, 'BIO') cur.execute(q, args)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.

Comment: I'm passing a string in the dept variable.

Comment: Please check my solution again, notice I have a comma inserted within parentheses so *args* passes a tuple of one length. Alternatively pass as a list: `args=[dept+'%']`.

Answer (score 0):

While using `.execute` you need to pass the argument as a list or tuple, here is the sample

```
# This is the qmark style:
cur.execute("insert into people values (?, ?)", (who, age))
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the ? and resolve your sql syntax so dept is treated as a variable e.g. sql should evaluate to

SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM Courses WHERE
                        Course LIKE  'mydept%'

Note you may be susceptible to sql injection with this method and dept is from user input

Comment: I dont know what language you are using but if you tried in sql it does work. Your string should evaluate to SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM Courses WHERE
                        Course LIKE  ('mydepthere%')

Comment: I'm using python.

Comment: I'm not a python developer but I am assuming you are passing the string with single quote around SQL. So example would be: dept = 'mydept'
sql = '\'SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM Courses WHERE Course LIKE \'' + dept + '%\')\'' 
print sql

Comment: If you don't need the single quote surrounding sql then this will work as well:  sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM Courses WHERE Course LIKE \'' + dept + '%\''

Comment: Sorry my earlier had a syntax error. The single quote example should be: sql = '\'SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM Courses WHERE Course LIKE \'' + dept + '%\'\''